# Try to use Symfony mailer with Gmail

Tags: symfony

Try to use Symfony mailer with Gmail on my Symfony 5.1 app.

mailer.yaml:

```
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'
```

.env:

```
MAILER_DSN=gmail+smtp://myadresse@gmail.com:mypassword@localhost
```

But each time I send a mail, I got:

```
Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465": stream_socket_client():
SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

Don't understand why... According to the https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html it should work.

I activated low security app on my Gmail account.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use Gmail, you need the package `symfony/google-mailer` (`composer require symfony/google-mailer`)

And this configuration in your .env file:

```
###> symfony/google-mailer ###
# Gmail SHOULD NOT be used on production, use it in development only.
MAILER_DSN=gmail://YourEmailAddress:YourPassword@default?verify_peer=0
###< symfony/google-mailer ###
```

An example:

```
MAILER_DSN=gmail://stackoverflow@gmail.com:admin123@default?verify_peer=0
```

**[Warning](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#tls-peer-verification):**

> Although it’s not recommended to disable this verification for
> security reasons, it can be useful while developing the application or
> when using a self-signed certificate

Comment: I forgot to precise but of course I installed symfony/google-mailer, and if I put MAILER_DSN=gmail://myadresse@gmail.com:mypassword@default I got nearly the same error: Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465": stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed

Comment: Try with `?verify_peer=0` at the end of your DSN. See [doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html#tls-peer-verification)

Comment: Indeed, it's working without TLS Peer Verification, with: MAILER_DSN=smtp://myadresse@gmail.com:mypassword@smtp.gmail.com?verify_peer=0. Don't know if it a good idea to disabled TLS Peer Verification but, it works... Thanks Liscare

Comment: Doesn't work at all. Symfony has so low quality of the email documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I know you've said you've done it, but I usually get this error because I need to allow "less secure apps" on my Gmail account.

1. Connect to Gmail
2. Go to https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps and click Authorize
3. Go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click Continue
4. Retry sending an email from your website, and if it still doesn't work **repeat points 2 & 3**. Sometimes I have to try a few times...

Answer (score 1):

That can come from an async property that is defined by config/packages/messenger.yaml
see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/45811

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are using an SSL certificate when sending emails through Gmail.

See:

https://symfony.com/doc/3.0//email/gmail.html

Comment: But I'm using Symfony 5.1 Mailer, not Swiftmailer. The config is not the same